# KILLED/ROLLBACK query doesn't stop running

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, kill

I've tried to kill a query on ms sql server management studio. 
Now it has the status  killed/rollback.

When I use: kill 74 with statusonly it doesn't make any progress. It is still at 0%. How can I delete this query without restarting the sql server?

I will really appreciate all your answers.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/08/31/sql-server-spid-is-killedrollback-state-what-to-do-next/

Comment: I have seen this blog. But you must restart the sql server. I wonder if there's a command to hard kill the query so that you don't have to restart the server.

Comment: I've seen rollback take a long time, is it a large commitment of data?  how long was it altering before it went into rollback?  It can take longer to rollback than it took to run in the first place

Comment: Actually, I execute a powershell script.It doesn't do anything with the database yet. the powershell script went into a loop and now it keeps running. So if I can make a hard kill, it will doesn't do anything harm. And it is almost for hours that it stuck at 0%.

Comment: Are you sure your script did not restart query right after kill? Are you running on real server or on laptop or something?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I am running this on a real server.

Comment: Use sp_who2 or sp_whoisactive to see whats happening. Sometime a rollback just takes a long time. I don't know how powershell comes into this.

Comment: Go to task manager and see if poweshell exe is running on it or not? Check the account it is using to run. If it is the one you are looking for, just kill it and rollback should complete. The think the problem here is process outside of SQL Server. Kill that and your rollback should complete.

Answer (score 2):

Even if not applicable here, please be wary of runaway queries initiated from an OPENQUERY command.  These run on remote servers, and continue to do so no matter how many times the user tries to cancel from their SSMS console....these pass-thru queries will continue to run on the target server. And if, God forbid, there's a recursive loop in there, it'll keep on running until the kill command is issued from the remote server end

Answer (score 1):

You have to be very careful. Assuming your query is not restarting and you have a `rollback` for that SPID.
If you restart SQL Server it won't help, because transaction still would have to be rolled back.
The problem with that is following: When you run a transaction in multi-CPU environment with not restricted degree of parallelism it most probably will generate parallel execution plan.
 Would say your transaction run for 10 minutes on 8 CPUs.
When you Killed it, `ROLLBACK` will be processed ONLY by ONE CPU. That means it might take up to 8 times longer to recover.